# Connect in GCloud Postgres SQL with nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm currently taking a beating from GCP

I have two projects in my GCP. The first have a Postgresql instance. The second has a nodejs environment that I want to connect to in the postgres of the first project.

But, I'm not able to connect. I'm reciving a lot of errors. In the https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin/overview I can see these examples:

```
2018-07-20 15:05:02.000 BRT
googleapi: Error 403: The client is not authorized to make this request., notAuthorized
{
 insertId:  "1vzsx8tf1jtki8"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName:  "projects/project-id-of-second-instance/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fstderr"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-07-20T18:05:37.273520497Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 textPayload:  "    googleapi: Error 403: The client is not authorized to make this request., notAuthorized
"  
 timestamp:  "2018-07-20T18:05:02Z"  
}
```

and

```
2018-07-20 15:12:37.000 BRT
{ Error: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/project-id-of-first-instance:us-central1:data-base/.s.PGSQL.5432 at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11) at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20) at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
 {
 insertId:  "epf1xrg1bzoqkb"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName:  "projects/project-id-of-second-instance/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fstdout"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-07-20T18:12:40.285974486Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 textPayload:  "{ Error: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/project-id-of-first-instance:us-central1:data-base/.s.PGSQL.5432
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
"  
 timestamp:  "2018-07-20T18:12:37Z"  
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the options for [accessing your Cloud SQL instances](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/instance-access-control#instanceaccess)? You have mentioned a 'nodejs environment' but you didn't mention if it's [from App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine), from a program running [in Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-compute-engine) or [an external app](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app)

Comment: Additional to the details asked by @Mangu, the first error you are getting, 403, is related with failed authentication. Can you double-check if the account that you are connecting with has the necessary [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/project-access-control#roles)?